# Error :The referenced entity (node: 252287) is invalid.?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have a node reference field (which is reference for node B) in a node A .When a user who does not have permissions for node B accesses the node A, the problem occurs when node A form is submitted it gives the following error:

```
The referenced entity (node: 252287) is invalid.
```

The nid shown above is the selected nid for the node reference field.
The workflow is as follows:
1. One user submits the form (node A) who has access to node B
2. Other user submits the form (node B) who  does not have access to node B.
But when the other user tries submitting he gets the error mentioned above.

Even after providing node access for (node B) to the user is not able to submit the form .
How can I solve the problem?
In the hook_node_access_records the code was as follows:

```
$deny_access_types = array( 'node_B', 'node C');
  if (in_array($node->type, $deny_access_types)) {
    $grants[] = array(
      'realm' => 'test_all',
      'gid' => 0,
      'grant_view' => 0,
      'grant_update' => 0,
      'grant_delete' => 0,
      'priority' => 0,
    );
  }
```

Now I have changed the code to

```
 $deny_access_types = array( 'node_B', 'node C');
      if (in_array($node->type, $deny_access_types)) {
        $grants[] = array(
          'realm' => 'test_all',
          'gid' => 0,
          'grant_view' => 1,
          'grant_update' => 1,
          'grant_delete' => 1,
          'priority' => 0,
        );
      }
```

But till it does not work 
Also changed the permission from the UI but still not works ?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding node access permissions?

Comment: pls check the upadated answer